# RoR login into page and post data to remote url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, external

here's my problem:

I need to post data from RoR server to remote PHP server, to a specific url, but before that I need to authenticate.. any help is much appreciated..

What I have done so far..

```
#sample data
postparams ={'id'=>1, 'name'=>'Test', 'phone'=>'123123123'}
#url - is in form http://domain.com/some/somemore
#user - contains username
#pass - contains password

require "uri"
require "net/http"

uri = URI(url)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.set_form_data(postparams)

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end

case res
when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
 #all ok
else
  res.value
end
```

Obviously I get 403.. because I'm not authorized? How do I authorize?

I also tried my luck with mechanize gem (below - using the same "sample" data\vars)

```
#when not logged in it renders login form
login_form = agent.get(url).forms.first
login_form.username = user
login_form.password = pass

# submit login form
agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)

#not sure how to submit to url..
#note that accessing url will not render the from 
#(I can't access it as I did with login form) - I simply need to post postparams
#to this url... and get the response code..
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the mechanize gem is your best choice.

[Here](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) is an example showing how to post a file to flicker using mechanize.
Maybe you could easily adapt to your needs:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

abort "#{$0} login passwd filename" if (ARGV.size != 3)

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  # Flickr refreshes after login
  agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
}

a.get('http://flickr.com/') do |home_page|
  signin_page = a.click(home_page.link_with(:text => /Sign In/))

  my_page = signin_page.form_with(:name => 'login_form') do |form|
    form.login  = ARGV[0]
    form.passwd = ARGV[1]
  end.submit

  # Click the upload link
  upload_page = a.click(my_page.link_with(:text => /Upload/))

  # We want the basic upload page.
  upload_page = a.click(upload_page.link_with(:text => /basic Uploader/))

  # Upload the file
  upload_page.form_with(:method => 'POST') do |upload_form|
    upload_form.file_uploads.first.file_name = ARGV[2]
  end.submit
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest the use of ruby [rest-client](https://github.com/adamwiggins/rest-client) gem.